# Sending an email including an attachment, based on the contents of the document library (Sharepoint, Power Automate, O365)

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, sharepointdocumentlibrary, o365-flow

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/op7n1.png)I'm solving a problem.
I have a library of documents:
I need to send an email once a year to the person specified in the row, at the same time I need to send a file that is inside the folder.

Structure in attachment:

I expect to send an email with the file once a year.
[enter image description here][enter image description here][enter image description here]

The email arrives, but the attachment contains no data.
Example, an xls attachment that is named correctly, but there is no data inside the document.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: here is detail of me flow: